# A simple scenario in Java where replacing a single character with a back slash requires four back slashes

Tags: java

Let's consider the following code snippet in Java.

```
package escape;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {            
         String s = "abc/xyz";
         System.out.println(s.replaceAll("/", "\\\\"));
    }
}
```

---

I just want to replace "/" with "\" in the above String **abc/xyz** and which is done and displays **abc\xyz** as expected but I couldn't get why it requires back slashes four times. It looks like two back slashes are sufficient. Why such is not a case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that `String.replaceAll` uses regular expressions (and actually calls [Matcher.replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) which does document this). In regular expressions you have to escape the '\' also in string literals you have to escape the '\'. Your 4 slashes are two slashes in the java string. And thereby an escaped slash in the regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape back slash once`\\` for java `String` and one more time`\\` for `regex` replacement string.

From the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs ($) in the **replacement**
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use
>   `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired

```
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\")));
```

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to replace "/" with "\"

Then you should not be using a regular expression, which is overkill, and requires backslashes to be escaped (twice). Instead do

```
string.replace('/', '\\');
```

(Still need to escape it once)

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), if you use `replaceAll`, Java will treat the first parameter as a RegEx, and will assess special meaning for backslashes in the replacement string. Basically, `\1` would refer to the first matching glob in the regex... In this case you need to escape the backslashes so they're "litteral" backslashes for the String, and then you need to escape these a second time so that `replaceAll` doesn't try to treat them with a special meaning.